# Why is my text output from next() and prev() toggle incorrect?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When clicking the arrows to change the displayed option, the incorrect options is shown.

The user should be able click on the option menu to toggle it open/cosed and be able to click on a option to select it. Alternatively, the arrows could be used to toggle through the options instead.

This is the problematic code:

```
    <script>
    $("#arrow_left_physics").click(function() {
      var $selected = $(".left_menu_option_selected").removeClass("left_menu_option_selected");
      var divs = $("#left_menu__variant_physics").children();
        divs.eq((divs.index($selected) - 1) % divs.length).addClass("left_menu_option_selected");
        $("#left_menu_open .button-text").text($($selected).text());
        });
    $("#arrow_right_physics").click(function() {
        var $selected = $(".left_menu_option_selected").removeClass("left_menu_option_selected");
        var divs = $selected.parent().children();
        divs.eq((divs.index($selected) + 1) % divs.length).addClass("left_menu_option_selected");
        $("#left_menu_open .button-text").text($($selected).text());
    });
    </script>
```

```js
$("#menu_open").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggle();
});



$(".menu_option").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass(".menu_option_selected")) {} else {
    $(".menu_option").removeClass("menu_option_selected");
    $(this).addClass("menu_option_selected");
    $("#menu_open .button_text").text($(this).text());
  }
});



$("#arrow_left").click(function() {
  var $selected = $(".menu_option_selected").removeClass("menu_option_selected");
  var options = $("#menu").children();
  options.eq((options.index($selected) - 1) % options.length).addClass("menu_option_selected");
  $("#menu_open .button_text").text($($selected).text());
});
$("#arrow_right").click(function() {
  var $selected = $(".menu_option_selected").removeClass("menu_option_selected");
  var options = $("#menu").children();
  options.eq((options.index($selected) + 1) % options.length).addClass("menu_option_selected");
  $("#menu_open .button_text").text($($selected).text());
});
```

```css
.menu_open {
  Cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.menu_option {
  Cursor: pointer;
  Padding: 5px;
}

.menu_option:hover {
  Background-Color: black;
  Color: white;
}

.menu_option_selected {
  color: green;
  Background-color: #00ff0a4d;
}

.menu_option_selected:hover {
  color: green;
}

.arrow {
  Cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="arrow" type="button" id="arrow_left" value="❮" />
  <input class="arrow" type="button" id="arrow_right" value="❯" />
</div>

<div>
  <button class="menu_open" id="menu_open">
    <span class="button_text">option1</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="menu" id=menu>
  <div class="menu_option menu_option_selected">option1</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option2</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option3</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option4</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option5</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option6</div>
</div>
```

-It seems that the first click of the arrows isn't working and that the index function is incorrect somewhere.

Comment: you're off by one. the default value is option0 yet there is no option0. either add option zero or change the default option to 1.

Comment: Didnt fix it for me. Are you talking about the jquery or the html?

Comment: The problem only happens the first time you click in the opposite direction.

Comment: No, the first click doesn't work, so the display is left behind. -I just changed the default value to make it more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$("#menu_open .button_text").text($($selected).text());
```

`$($selected)` is the option that was previously selected, so you're showing the text of the previous option, not the current option. (BTW, there's no need to wrap `$selected` in `$()`, since it's already a jQuery object.)

You should use `$(".menu_option_selected").text()` instead of `$($selected).text()` to get the current option.

You should also make the initial text of the button `option1`, so it matches the selected option.

```js
$("#menu_open").click(function() {
  $("#menu").toggle();
});

$(".menu_option").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass(".menu_option_selected")) {} else {
    $(".menu_option").removeClass("menu_option_selected");
    $(this).addClass("menu_option_selected");
    $("#menu_open .button_text").text($(this).text());
  }
});

$("#arrow_left").click(function() {
  var $selected = $(".menu_option_selected").removeClass("menu_option_selected");
  var options = $("#menu").children();
  options.eq((options.index($selected) - 1) % options.length).addClass("menu_option_selected");
  $("#menu_open .button_text").text($(".menu_option_selected").text());
});
$("#arrow_right").click(function() {
  var $selected = $(".menu_option_selected").removeClass("menu_option_selected");
  var options = $("#menu").children();
  options.eq((options.index($selected) + 1) % options.length).addClass("menu_option_selected");
  $("#menu_open .button_text").text($(".menu_option_selected").text());
});
```

```css
.menu_open {
  Cursor: pointer;
}

.menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.menu_option {
  Cursor: pointer;
  Padding: 5px;
}

.menu_option:hover {
  Background-Color: black;
  Color: white;
}

.menu_option_selected {
  color: green;
  Background-color: #00ff0a4d;
}

.menu_option_selected:hover {
  color: green;
}

.arrow {
  Cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <input class="arrow" type="button" id="arrow_left" value="❮" />
  <input class="arrow" type="button" id="arrow_right" value="❯" />
</div>

<div>
  <button class="menu_open" id="menu_open">
    <span class="button_text">option1</span>
  </button>
</div>

<div class="menu" id=menu>
  <div class="menu_option menu_option_selected">option1</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option2</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option3</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option4</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option5</div>
  <div class="menu_option">option6</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another version, refactoring your javascript code with some [Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

```
const setButtonText = () => {
  $("#menu_open .button_text").text(
    $(".menu_option_selected").text()
  );    
}

const moveSelection = direction => {
  var selected = $(".menu_option_selected")
  var options = $("#menu").children()
  var newIndex;
  if (direction == 'right') {
    newIndex = (options.index(selected) + 1) % options.length
  } else {
    newIndex = (options.index(selected) - 1) % options.length
  }
  selected.removeClass("menu_option_selected")
  options.eq(newIndex).addClass("menu_option_selected")
  setButtonText()
}


// inizilize menu button_text
setButtonText()

$("#arrow_left").click(() => moveSelection('left'));

$("#arrow_right").click( () => moveSelection('right'));

$("#menu_open").click( () => $("#menu").toggle());

$(".menu_option").click( function() {
    $(".menu_option_selected").removeClass("menu_option_selected")
    $(this).addClass("menu_option_selected")
  setButtonText()
});
```